# Reading from Properties file v/s HashMap lookup

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Which is a more efficient way of accessing (key,value) pairs in terms of both memory and computation: reading from a properties file using properties.getProperty("key") or loading the entire properties file into a HashMap in the beginning of the program and then looking up for the key in HashMap?

Also, if only 1 of the values from the properties is used repeatedly, will it be better to store the value in a member variable and access it or look it up each time using properties.getProperty("key")?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`properties.getProperty("key")` is a lookup from the Hashtable that is the Properties object. When you do `Properties.load()`, you load the entries from a file and store them into the Properties object, which extends Hashtable. Every subsequent access to a property does a lookup in the Hashtable. There is no file IO anymore.

Of course accessing a member variable is slightly faster than accessing a value from a key in a HashMap, but I doubt that this is where you'll gain anything significant in performance. a HashMap lookup is O(1), and is damn fast. You would probably need millions of lookups before noticing a difference. Do what is the most readable for you.

Comment: I disagree with the millions of lookups. OK, if the lookups are spread over time, they probably won't make much of a difference, but if the property is accessed regularly during a longer-running operation, it should make a difference. Keep in mind that a hash lookup potentially involves traversing a (short) linked list and that the string hash code (which luckily is already cached in the string) needs to be translated to a bucket index first. Those may all be cheap operations, but they add up.

Comment: On a micro-benchmark, without any warmup phase to make sure everything is jitted and thus faster, with a Properties object containing 100 keys, it only takes 85 milliseconds to perform 1 million Properties lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `System.getProperty()` uses a `java.util.Properties` object internally. The `Properties` class extends `HashTable<Object,Object>`, so sou are unlikely to gain much performance by explicitly using a `HashMap` instead.

However, if you are using few properties very often, it will certainly help if you store these in variables. HashTable/HashMap lookup and variable access may both be O(1), but HashTable lookup definitely has a much larger constant factor.